# Get the positions of LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wonder if there is a way to get the positions of nodes in a line renderer. In the project I'm working on I have a `PseudoLine` game object on which I have a line renderer. When I draw a line, I clone `PseudoLine` to create a new line. Using simply:

```
Instantiate(gameObject);
```

What I want to do is create new gameobjects with a prefab, which also has a line renderer on it. I want to copy the positions of `PseudoLine` to my new game object's line renderer. Something like this:

```
GameObject tempLine = Instantiate(line);
tempLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPositions(transform.gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().Positions);
```

I checked the documentation and couldn't find any helpful built-in functions. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`LineRenderer.GetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) and the [`LineRenderer.GetPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPosition.html) functions to get the position of the `LineRenderer`.

It's recommended to use the [`LineRenderer.GetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) function in this case since you are making a whole copy of the postions and [`LineRenderer.GetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) will be fast for this.

To do this you need to create new `Vector3` array and the length of this array should be the 
[`LineRenderer.numPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-numPositions.html) value of the old `LineRenderer` you want to duplicate. In new version of *Unity(5.6)*, this variable has been renamed to  [`LineRenderer.positionCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html).

---

```
GameObject oldLine = gameObject;
GameObject newLine = Instantiate(oldLine);

LineRenderer oldLineComponent = oldLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

//Get old Position Length
Vector3[] newPos = new Vector3[oldLineComponent.positionCount];
//Get old Positions
oldLineComponent.GetPositions(newPos);

//Copy Old postion to the new LineRenderer
newLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPositions(newPos);
```